# Gradient border on click

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap

I've been noticing that if clicking on a button on my site (as shown in the example below) a gradient border is shown around the button. I've tried several browsers but this only shows in Google Chrome.

Is there a way of removing this CSS wize?

[image]

Comment: I almost thought you fabricated this question just so people would click the upvote arrow. Looks almost identical to Stack.

Comment: @TreeTree I'm sure a couple of those upvotes were people testing it out :)

Comment: @TreeTree: Haha! There's a reason for me not choosing a pic when I clicked the downvote button ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the outline with `outline:none`.

```
input,
select,
textarea,
button {
  outline: none;
}
```

And to stay safe with focus states:

```
input:focus,
select:focus,
textarea:focus,
button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

However, some think it isn't a good idea to disable the outline due to accessibility issues (http://outlinenone.com/)

Comment: +1 for the link, I use tab navigation quite often as it's much faster than mouse in many cases. Make sure to provide another visual clue to the focused element when removing its outline.

Answer (score 0):

This is to show that the element is active. To disable this:

```
#element.focus{
    outline:0;
}
```